# Is there a way in *R plots* to label the lines at the end of each line on a multiple line plot?

Tags: r, label, line-plot

I am looking to add labels to the end of each line on a multiple line plot using R plots - not ggplot2! I have 7 lines on my plot and a legend is looking too confusing.

The result I would like to see is 7 labels, which each at the end of one of the lines on the plot. Ideally, the label would be in the same color as the line. I know there is a solution with ggplot2, but looking at R plots at the moment.

Comment: Look into `text()`. You can include text anywhere in the plot by specifying the position.

Comment: nice! thanks, I'll look into it!